# Plotting outside Excel using xlwings

Tags: matplotlib, xlwings

I'm calling some Python code from Excel using xlwings. I want to plot some of the results in a scatter-plot and I have the code below:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    x = data['X']
    y = data['Y']
    z = data['Z']

    # Filter out elements that work
    z[z<1] = np.nan

    length, width = section_properties.shape

    fig = plt.figure()

#    # Create Map
    cm = plt.get_cmap("RdYlGn")
    col = np.arange(length)

#    Create 3D plot
    ax3D = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    p3d = ax3D.scatter(x, y, z, c=col, marker='o') 
    ax3D.set_xlabel('X label')
    ax3D.set_ylabel('Y label')
    ax3D.set_zlabel('Z label')

#    Option 1: show on Excel (static)
    sht = xw.Book.caller().sheets['Results']
    sht.pictures.add(fig, name='MyPlot', update=True)

    # Option 2: show on its own window (interactive)
#   plt.show()
```

Option 1 works well and places the 3D scatter plot on the Excel worksheet. The only problem with this is that the plot is static (ie I can't rotate it or zoom in and out). I was hoping the code I put under option 2 would create a plot outside Excel which I could manipulate, but it does not work.

Is there a way to produce such a plot on a new window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into the same problem, I fixed it by producing an HTML file with plotly, that I then visualize in the browser. See code below.

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import plotly.io as pio

    pio.renderers.default = "browser"

    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=12,
            color=z,                # set color to an array/list of desired values
            colorscale='Rainbow',   # choose a colorscale
            opacity=0.8
        )
    )])

    # tight layout
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
    fig.write_html('tmp.html', auto_open=True)
```

Thanks!